# Polynomial equations with linear inequalities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Given a set of polynomials equations in variables $x_1\dots x_n$ and a set of linear inequalities $L_k(x_1\dots x_n)\ne0$, is the set of solutions an algebraic set? If it is, what is the corresponding set of polynomials?

PS: if the number of solutions with the inequalities included is finite, the answer to the first question is yes. What are the corresponding polynomials?

Comment: The solution is in general not an algebraic set, for example $k\backslash\{0\}$, where $k$ is your field. Such sets (defined by polynomial equations and inequalities) are called semialgebraic.

Comment: Ah right, let me restate the question.

Comment: Such sets will at least be constructible sets, which is a broader class than algebraic sets.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_set_(topology)

Answer (score 1):

This is to answer the question in PS.

When the number of solutions is finite, each $L_k$ takes on them a finite number of nonzero values. Let $S_k$ denote the set of these values. Then we can replace each $L_k(x_1,\dots,x_n)\ne 0$ with a single polynomial equation:
$$\prod_{s\in S_k} (L_k(x_1,\dots,x_n) - s)=0.$$
These equations together with the original polynomial equations define the same set of solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the number of solutions is finite with the inequalities included.

Comment: Yes, this is how I interpreted the question. What is your concern?

Comment: Ah ok, it is right. I  am wondering if the set of polynomials generates a radical ideal if the original polynomials without inequalities do.